# How to combine double rows keeping all unique data in column 2

Tags: sorting, unix, awk

I am trying to merge identical rows based on the identifier in column 1. The info in column 2 is not necessarily identical. How can I fuse doubles keeping all unique records of the second column?

Example of first three rows of my data:

```
>TRINITY_DN100377_c0_g1  GO:0046556,GO:0009044,GO:0045493,
>TRINITY_DN10038_c0_g1  GO:0005783,GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0004581,
>TRINITY_DN10038_c0_g1   GO:0005789,GO:0004598
```

I want to get:

```
>TRINITY_DN100377_c0_g1  GO:0046556,GO:0009044,GO:0045493,
>TRINITY_DN10038_c0_g1  GO:0005783,GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0004581,GO:0004598,
```

So simply fuse doubles but keeping all uniques of column 2.

I am using:

```
cat file | sort -u | awk '!seen[$1]++' > newfile
```

But this results only in that the first row of doubles are kept, the rest are deleted.

Can someone help me, how do I keep all unique GO terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev {
    printf "%s%s  ", (NR>1 ? ORS : ""), $1
    delete seen
    prev = $1
}
{
    n = split($2,tmp,/,/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        val = tmp[i]
        if ( (val != "") && !seen[val]++ ) {
           printf "%s,", val
        }
    }
}
END { print "" }
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>TRINITY_DN100377_c0_g1  GO:0046556,GO:0009044,GO:0045493,
>TRINITY_DN10038_c0_g1  GO:0005783,GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0004581,GO:0004598,
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, it works perfectly! Also makes me realise I really need to dive into AWK.. :-)

@Tiw, both lines of code do not do the trick. It does remove the first "," of the second column and the last "," in case of the second line of code..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the order (GNU awk):

```
awk -F'[, ]*' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i!="")a[$1][$i]}END{for(k in a){printf "%s ", k; for(j in a[k]) printf "%s,", j;print ""}} ' file
>TRINITY_DN100377_c0_g1 GO:0046556,GO:0009044,GO:0045493,
>TRINITY_DN10038_c0_g1 GO:0004581,GO:0005783,GO:0004598,GO:0016021,GO:0005789,
```

And if you want to remove the last `,`:

```
awk -F'[, ]*' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i!="")a[$1][$i]}END{for(k in a){e=sprintf("%s ", k); for(j in a[k]) e=e sprintf("%s,", j);sub(/.$/,"",e);print e}} ' file
>TRINITY_DN100377_c0_g1 GO:0046556,GO:0009044,GO:0045493
>TRINITY_DN10038_c0_g1 GO:0004581,GO:0005783,GO:0004598,GO:0016021,GO:0005789
```